# How to get per core statistics for the Kubernetes pod that is displayed like “mptstats” statistics?

Tags: linux, cpu, kubernetes

I would want to find the per core usage statistics for my Kubernetes pod.

In my Linux host/in the Kubernetes node, I use `mpstat` to find the statistics like below.

[image]

In my case, I assign 2.5 CPUs to the Kubernetes container and when I try the same `mpstat` command from inside the container, I get the same details as above showing all the host CPUs (16 in my case).

I used `kubectl top` command, but it just shows the overall CPU used by the pod but not per CPU statistics assigned to the container.

Prometheus' `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` gives a similar overall details but not individual CPU details.

How do I get `mpstat` like statistics, like shown above, for the Kubernetes pod.